# PHP file_exists (overwriting file) not working

Tags: php

I followed the answer on the question about uploading images and overwriting the existing file.

The suggested answer is to use the method `file_exists()`. I used the same method but the image is not overwriting the existing image when I tried to upload a different image but the same filename.

here is my php code:

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","japorms");


$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$base_picture = $_POST["base_picture"];


$binary = base64_decode($base_picture);



if (file_exists('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg'))
{

    unlink('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg');

}

    $file = fopen('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);


$response["success"]=true;


echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**SOLVED**

I rearranged and fixed my code. it's working now. thanks for all your suggestions.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","japorms");
/*$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.ph","u989983246_jap","japorms","u989983246_jap");
*/


$user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
$base_picture = $_POST["base_picture"];


$binary = base64_decode($base_picture);



if (file_exists('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg'))
{

    unlink('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg');
    $file = fopen('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);


}
else{


    $file = fopen('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);


}



$response["success"]=true;


echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: $k= unlink('user_img/'.$user_id.'.jpg'); var_dump($k); die; Check what this code shows.. I think it is realted to permission

Comment: A side note: you should _never_ use client side provided data in such way. Imagine someone posts a value like `user_id=../../../../etc/passwd`... Instead store such data inside the database (using prepared statements and parameter bindings of course to prevent sql injection attacks) and internal, maybe time string or counter based names.

Comment: @arkascha this php file is accompanied to android. and in android, i am checking if the image is valid or not. so there will be no problems in the "values".

Comment: @Confused will do. thanks

Comment: This code is very dangerous. Do not use `$_POST` value to be file names. Also, did you check the return value of `unlink()`?

Comment: Remember that client side provided data can very easily be modified. Either on protocol level (interception) or by faking a request. You definitely risk to run into problems by what you plan.

Comment: @Raptor how is it dangerous? can you please elaborate.?

Comment: @arkascha I think that's where quality assurance comes in. =)

Comment: No idea what you mean by that. The code you implement has to be robust ans save no matter what data you are handed. Period. Sure, quality assurance and trust are useful things. But they do _not_ replace programming craftsmanship.

Comment: @arkascha I'm still a beginner so I guess I'll discover those things and learn from whatever errors may come. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Sure, that is perfectly fine! We all learn all the time! All I say is: don't start off in a way that if questionable per definition. Do not raise bad habits. Instead wrap your thoughts about the idea of differing between user provided data, never use such data internally for anything, only store it in a database and hand it out again where required. That actually is much easier and cleaner than the other way 'round, since you prevent to bloat your code afterwards when trying to add protection against various threads. Stay clean from the beginning. And now: have fun!

Comment: About your issue itself: most likely you have a file permission issue which prevents that the existing file gets deleted. Take a look into your http servers error log file (you need to monitor that file anyway when implementing in a web environment). That is where you can see any issues your code throws up. Keep in mind that the process the http server is executed under (so your php script) differs in user account and permissions from your personal account.

Comment: What's your the return code for `unlink()`? `unlink()` isn't really necessary when the `w` option of `fopen()` is in effect, because it [places the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: @TryingtobeNerd I think the 2nd comment has already explained in detail. Also, please read the PHP documentation carefully. The code looks very immature (e.g. lack of return value checking, assume the code runs without error, etc). From your latest code, you don't even check if the file handle is created successfully or not.

Comment: @Raptor the filename of the image is programmatically set to the id of the user based on its value on the database. The user doesn't have the permission to set the filename of his/her choice and the files are filtered to be in jpg format and also checks if the dimension of the image exceeds the available resolution. You're concluding without even asking. Sory for being "Immature". P.S. I'm not the type of programmer that makes apps like "It's ok if it runs".

Comment: POST request can easily be emulated & replayed by other script / client . Even Chrome has extension for that, so you can't assume that it is safe